# How many different ways can the kinds of milk to buy be selected?

Tags: combinatorics

This combinatorics problem is giving me a hard time:

A grocery store stocks 1-gallon cartons of skim milk, 1% milk, 2% milk, and whole milk. A customer is asked to buy 10 gallons of milk. The customer needs to buy at least one carton of each type of milk.

How many different ways can the kinds of milk to buy be selected?

The answer is supposed to be 84 however I am not sure how to arrive at that
answer. I saw a similar question with the stars and bars method used however
I don't fully understand how to implement that method into the context of this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milk of the same type is indistinguishable.  So all gallons of 2% milk (for example) look alike.

To understand this answer, please read [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) closely.

**If** there was no constraint re at least one of each type of milk has to be bought, **then** the answer would be

$$\binom{10 + [4-1]}{[4-1]}.$$

However, since at least one of each type has to be bought, when considering the number of integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$$

The lower bound for each variable is $1$, rather than $0$.

This **bijects** to the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 6$$

which will have

$$\binom{6 + [4-1]}{[4-1]} = \binom{9}{3} ~\text{solutions}.$$

Comment: Where did the [4-1] come from in the beginning? I understand that there are four options (types of milk) but what is the meaning of the minus one?

Comment: @apthewiz If you read the cited article, you will see that the number of non-negative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$ is $$\binom{n + [k-1]}{[k-1]}.$$

Comment: At the risk of further irritating you, how did you arrive at 6? I read the article and it mentions what a bijection is, but how exactly is 6 computed?

Comment: @apthewiz No problem.  Consider the change of variables, $y_1 = (x_1 - 1), \cdots, y_4 = (x_4 - 1).$  Then, there is a **bijection** between each solution of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$, where each of $x_1, \cdots, x_4$ is $\geq 1$  and each solution of $y_1 + \cdots + y_4 = 6$, where each of $y_1, \cdots, y_4$ is $\geq 0.$

Comment: Ohhh ok, so in layman's terms, since the minimum value of each of the four x values (x1, x2, x3, x4) is 1 (since a value of 0 for any of the x values would imply exclusion of the type of milk) then the minimum total sum of the values is 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4, thus giving us 6 from 10-4=6. Thanks!

Comment: @apthewiz Yes, now you've got it.

Answer (score -1):

Ans is $4^{6}$

Explanation:
After getting at least one gallon of each type, There are 4 ways for each next six gallon can be bought.

Comment: The answer is supposed to be 84

Comment: I see my mistake now